# On which site should I ask for opinions about using var in C#?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question, but not sure if it should be asked at Stack Overflow, here in Meta or in Programmers. It is potentially a discussion, but I'm after opinions.

The question is along the lines of implicit coding or explicit coding.

Where is the best place to ask?

This means I have to ask it here to then be told where it will be answered!

My question is, in programming it is my understanding that generally being explicit is desired (as opposed to being implicit), so is the use of the`var keyword so popular.

```
var myName = DateTime.Now();
```

Comment: Don't. Search, it's been asked before...

Comment: *"but I'm after opinions"*... that's a pretty good indicator you shouldn't ask it.

Comment: And please do take care of your markdown. A lot of content was invisible and only upon editing I saw there was more. Check your posts before you post them (and after as well).

Comment: Step 1: See how much content has been posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp) Step 2: don't ask a new question.

Answer (score 6):

There is this already asked and answered on Programmers:  [Explicitly defining variable data types vs. using the keyword 'var'?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42863/c-explicitly-defining-variable-data-types-vs-using-the-keyword-var). It sounds to me like it covers the practical ground behind your question ("when to use var").

Asking whether or not `var` is popular, why it is or isn't popular, or how many people use it is best done elsewhere (for example, on Quora or Reddit) because all those questions are essentially discussion-starters for folks to share their theories and opinions.

Comment: Yup; and my bet is, if you go to Reddit or Quora, you will find *lots* of examples of already-started discussions on the topic.

Comment: Well, questions like this can often be answered by recommended standards and guidelines provided by those responsible for the thing, which can hold more ground than mere opinions.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment We've done this dance with `var` before. You're right, some of these questions *can* be answered, but in this case they either already have been or never will be, depending slightly on the specific flavour of the question.

Comment: "Recommended standards and guidelines"? Whose? What authority would you accept? What authority will the next user accept?